# How to select featureMember by gml:id in WFS 2.0

Tags: wfs, filter

In WFS 1.1.0 I could filter like this:

```
<ogc:Filter>
<ogc:GmlObjectId gml:id="5"/>
</ogc:Filter>
```

Is there an equivalent in WFS 2.0?

I've tried:

```
<fes:Filter>
    <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <fes:ValueReference>gml:id</fes:ValueReference>
        <fes:Literal>B6_Aardgastransportleidingen.2</fes:Literal>
    </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
</fes:Filter>
```

But this returns an exception

```
<ows:ExceptionText>Illegal property name: gml:id for feature type B64_nutsvoorzieningen:B6_Aardgastransportleidingen</ows:ExceptionText>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
<fes:Filter>
      <fes:ResourceId rid="B6_Aardgastransportleidingen.6" />
 </fes:Filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

In WFS 2.0 you can use the storedquery *GetFeatureById* so you might have a request like:

> http://xxx/minerals/services?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&STOREDQUERY_ID=urn:ogc:def:query:OGC-WFS::GetFeatureById&ID=M4EU.GE_190361&

You can check if your service has any storedqueries by looking at the GetCapabilities response:

```
<ows:Operation name="ListStoredQueries">
    <ows:DCP>
        <ows:HTTP>
            <ows:Get xlink:href="http://xxx/minerals/services?"/>
            <ows:Post xlink:href="http://xxx/minerals/services"/>
        </ows:HTTP>
    </ows:DCP>
    </ows:Operation>
    <ows:Operation name="DescribeStoredQueries">
    <ows:DCP>
        <ows:HTTP>
            <ows:Get xlink:href="http://xxx/minerals/services?"/>
            <ows:Post xlink:href="http://xxx/minerals/services"/>
        </ows:HTTP>
    </ows:DCP>
</ows:Operation>
```

List them through a request like:

> http://xxx/minerals/services?service=WFS&request=ListStoredQueries&version=2.0.0&

See how they are called through:

> http://xxx/minerals/services?service=WFS&request=DescribeStoredQueries&version=2.0.0&STOREDQUERY_ID=urn:ogc:def:query:OGC-WFS::GetFeatureById&